# APISubscriptionError-Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: python, instagram-api

I am trying to create a subscription using the `Instagram API` but am encountering the above error.

```
'''
Create Instagram Subscription 
'''
@app.route('/instagram-subscription-create', methods = ['POST'])                                                                            
def create_instagram_subscription():
    client_id = app.config['INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID']
    client_secret = app.config['INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET']
    api = InstagramAPI(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
    api.create_subscription(object='user', aspect='media', callback_url='https://my/url/instagram-subscription-update')

    // What to return here?


'''
Instagram Subscription Update
'''
@app.route('/instagram-subscription-update', methods = ['GET','POST'])                                                                          
def instagram_subscription_update():
    if request.method == 'GET':                             
        hub_mode = request.args.get('hub.mode')
        hub_challenge = request.args.get('hub.challenge')
        hub_verify_token = request.args.get('hub.verify_token')         
        return Response(hub_challenge )
```

I have tried logging `hub_challenge` and I'm definitely getting something back so I really don't know why it is saying that it can't reach the `callback URL` because it clearly is..?

Strangely when I run the call through a browser REST Client and address the request to: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/`

I get a response:

```
{
   meta: {
   code: 200
   }-
   data: {
         object: "user"
         object_id: null
         aspect: "media"
         callback_url: "https://my/url/instagram-subscription-update"
         type: "subscription"
         id: "20230475"
   }-
}
```

Also where I have specified above, what should I be returning?

Thanks for your help.

**NOTE**

I'm currently using `localtunnel` if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing right now trying to create a subscription, but I'm using golang with the `carbocation/go-instagram/` library. I can't seem to get the Instagram API to respond with anything but `Unable to reach callback URL` or `Invalid URL. The URL may be on a private network`